# Thread-safe memoizer

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, cache, memoization

I have searched around but I was not able to find a complete implementation of the memoize pattern in a multithreaded context. It's the first time playing with thread synchronization. The code seems to works, but I am not able to test it extensively, in particular to find if there are race conditions. Do you think there is a better implementation, maybe using more advanced synchronization mechanism?

```
from threading import Thread, Lock, current_thread
import thread

def memoize(obj):
    import functools
    cache = obj.cache = {}
    lock_cache = obj.lock_cache = Lock()

    @functools.wraps(obj)
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        key = str(args) + str(kwargs)
        cached_result = None
        item_lock = None
        with lock_cache:
            # do the minimal needed things here: just look inside the cache,
            # return if present, otherwise create and acquire lock  specific to a
            # particular computation. Postpone the actual computation, do  not
            # block other computation.
             cached_result = cache.get(key, None)
            if cached_result is not None:
                 if type(cached_result) is not thread.LockType:
                     return cached_result
            else:
                item_lock = Lock()
                item_lock.acquire()
                cache[key] = item_lock

        if item_lock is not None:
            # if we are here it means we have created the lock: do the
            # computation, return and release.
            result = obj(*args, **kwargs)
            with lock_cache:
                cache[key] = result
            item_lock.release()
            return result

        if type(cached_result) is thread.LockType:
            # if we are here it means that other thread have created the
            # locks and are doing the computation, just wait
            with cached_result:
                return cache[key]
    return memoizer
```

Here a little test:

```
import time

@memoize
def f(x):
    time.sleep(2)
    return x * 10

lock_write = Lock()
def worker(x):
    result = f(x)
    with lock_write:
        print current_thread(), x, result

threads = []

start = time.time()
for i in (0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3):
    t = Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

time.sleep(1)

for i in (0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3):
    t = Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()

print time.time() - start
```

I get the correct results and it runs in 2 seconds, as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Review

1. There's no docstring. What does `memoize` do, and how do I use it?
2. The code uses `str(args) + str(kwargs)` as the cache key. But this means that, for example, the number `1` and the string `"1"` will collide.
3. The code is not portable to Python 3, where there's no `thread` module.
4. It's not clear to me why `functools` is only imported inside `memoize`, but `threading` is imported at top level.
5. It's not clear to me why the code assigns to `obj.cache` and `obj.lock_cache`. What if `obj` already has a `cache` property?
6. The locking logic is hard to follow and needs comments. As far as I can see, `lock_cache` protects the `cache` dictionary; and `item_cache` protects the cache slot that is currently being computed. Its necessary to have two locks because the call to `obj` might be recursive and so need to re-enter `memoizer`.
7. The code uses three states for each key: (i) not present in the cache; (ii) currently being computed; (iii) present in the cache. The way it distinguishes between (ii) and (iii) is by checking to see if the type is `thread.LockType`. But this means that you can't use `memoize` on a function that might return a lock. It would be better to have a more robust mechanism for distinguishing these cases.
8. The naming is inconsistent: `lock_cache` versus `item_lock`.
9. `key` is looked up in `cache` multiple times on some code paths.

#### 2. Revised code

```
from functools import wraps
from threading import Lock

class CacheEntry: pass

def memoized(f):
    """Decorator that caches a function's result each time it is called.
    If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is
    returned, and not re-evaluated. Access to the cache is
    thread-safe.

    """
    cache = {}                  # Map from key to CacheEntry
    cache_lock = Lock()         # Guards cache

    @wraps(f)
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        key = args, tuple(kwargs.items())
        result_lock = None

        with cache_lock:
            try:
                entry = cache[key]
            except KeyError:
                entry = cache[key] = CacheEntry()
                result_lock = entry.lock = Lock() # Guards entry.result
                result_lock.acquire()

        if result_lock:
            # Compute the new entry without holding cache_lock, to avoid
            # deadlock if the call to f is recursive (in which case
            # memoizer is re-entered).
            result = entry.result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            result_lock.release()
            return result
        else:
            # Wait on entry.lock without holding cache_lock, to avoid
            # blocking other threads that need to use the cache.
            with entry.lock:
                return entry.result

    return memoizer
```

Notes:

1. This is untested.
2. This doesn't delete `result_lock` after the result is computed. This simplifies the logic (for example, there's no need to take `cache_lock` again and no need for a type check) at the cost of 40 bytes to keep the `Lock` object around.

Comment: thank you. Maybe there is a problem, suppose I call: `f(1); f(1); f(2)`. The last call is blocked by `cache_lock` acquired by the second call which is blocked by `entry.lock` acquired by the first call. But `f(1)` and `f(2)` should run in parallel.

Comment: I have updated the test code: with my solution I get 2 second, with yours 4.

Comment: This shows why you need comments in multi-threaded code!

Comment: Thank you, your last version works. I have commented my code.

Answer (score 3):

For the posterity:

- Multiple fixes have been applied during the following years in the `functools.lru_cache` built-in memoize function ([one example](https://bugs.python.org/issue28969))
- CPython [`test_functools.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/bc7f6fcdf14da32a8f7816ace800a6a91dc1554f/Lib/test/test_functools.py#L1638-L1727) includes tests that cover many multithreaded cases.

So it seems that you can now simply use this syntax to create a thread-safe memoizer:

```
import functools
import time

@functools.cache
def f(x):
  time.sleep(2)
  return x * 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries don't guarantee consistent ordrering of `.items()`, so `tuple(kwargs.items())` might return differently-ordered tuples for the same dict, potentially causing duplication in your cache. `frozenset(kwargs.items())` will work, but assumes the kwarg values are hashable—but, it looks like you already assume that your args are hashable, so this is probably fine here.

Turns out a general-purpose argument-based cache key for potentially non-hashable arguments is pretty hard to come by, so if you really want a general-purpose memoizer, you might consider adding an optional key function parameter to your decorator (Python 3 syntax):

```
def freeze(*args, **kwargs):
    return args, frozenset(kwargs.items())

def memoized(f=None, *, key_func=freeze):
    # Allow this parameterized decorator to work without being called
    if func is None:
        return partial(memoized, key_func=key_func)
    ...
    @wraps(f)
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        key = key_func(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
    return memoizer
```

Then you can use it with our without that parameter:

```
@memoized
def f():
    pass

@memoized(key_func=magic_serializer)
def g():
    pass

# Parentheses are legal but unnecessary here
@memoized()
def h():
    pass
```

(Or you just make sure everything is immutable and hashable and all your problems will disappear :)

I've got a recursive version of `freeze` that handles most common Python data structures lying around somewhere; I'll see if I can dig it up later. (Ping me if you're curious and it looks like I've forgotten.)